# ros::WallTime for cpp

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can i add a ros::wallTime stamp in my ros massage?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43984/ros::walltime-for-cpp/) by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
my_message_instance.header.stamp = ros::WalTime::now();
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on 2012-09-18**:
but i found a error in "rosmake My_package".             its showing that-----  Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!